# OOP(Object Oriented Programming) dilemma

Tags: python, object, pygame

So I need some advice/help on how to make this code/program more OOP(Object Oriented Programming).

I'll post the whole code here. I was planning to make separate modules but I'm really a noob at this.

Some backstory about the game: It's a game with first the start game screen, then the difficulty screen then the level one with the sheep and the fox(`player`) and then the level 2 with instead of the rabbits there's pigs and boars. Planning also a level three with three types of enemies.

So any help is appreciated, I just need some tips and such to transform this code to object oriented coding, which is easier to read and doesn't put so much strain on the CPU.

More progress on the main.py file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Så jag ska försöka göra koden objekt orienterad så man förstår bättre
#det är samt enklare att läsa.

import pygame, sys, random, math
from rabbits import Rabbit
from pigs import Pig
from boars import Boar
from pygame.locals import *
from threading import Timer

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

soundsDict = {"foxSound" : pygame.mixer.sound(sound/foxSound.wav), 
"rabbitSound" : pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds/rabbitSound.wav'), 
"pigSound" : pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds/pigSound.wav'), 
"boarSound" : pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds/boarSound.wav')}

musicDict = {"musicMenu" : pygame.mixer.Sound('music/Who Likes To Party.ogg')}

spriteDict = {"playerImage" : pygame.image.load('textures/Fox.png'), 
"playerImageTwo" : pygame.image.load('textures/Fox2.png'), 
"rabbitImage" : pygame.image.load('textures/topic_rabbit.png'), 
"rabbitImageTwo" : pygame.image.load('textures/topic_rabbit2.png'), 
"pigImage" : pygame.image.load('textures/Pig.png'), 
"pigImageTwo" : pygame.image.load('textures/Pig2.png'), 
"boarImage" : pygame.image.load('textures/Boar.png'), 
"boarImageTwo" : pygame.image.load('textures/Boar2.png')}

buttonDict = {"buttonEasyImage" : pygame.image.load('textures/buttonEasy.png'), 
"buttonNormalImage" : pygame.image.load('textures/buttonNormal.png'), 
"buttonHardImage" : pygame.image.load('textures/buttonHard.png')}



level = 1
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if level == 1:
            player.update()

            for rabbit in rabbits:
                rabbit.update()

        elif level == 2:
            player.update()

            for pig in pigs:
                pig.update()

    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))

    MOVE_SPEED = 0

    if level == 1:
        # Play level 2 music

        # Draw level 1 state to screen
        Player.update()
        Player.draw()
        for rabbit in rabbits:
            rabbit.draw(surface)

    elif level == 2: #I get a weird indentation error here*
        # Play level 2 music

        # Draw level 2 state to screen
        Player.update()
        Player.draw()
        for pig in pigs:
            pig.draw(surface)
        for boar in boars:
            boar.draw(surface)

    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(60)
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
So I've made some progress, just wanted your opinion if I'm heading in the
right direction, so to speak.

Here's the player.py file and the boars.py file for example (updated):

```
\player.py

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pygame, sys, random, math

class Player(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.moveRight = False
        self.moveLeft = False
        self.moveUp = False
        self.moveDown = False
    def process_event(event):
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                levelOne = False
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                self.moveRight = False
                self.moveLeft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                self.moveRight = True
                self.moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                self.moveDown = False
                self.moveUp = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                self.moveDown = True
                self.moveUp = False
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                self.moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                self.moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                self.moveUp = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                self.moveDown = False

    def update(self):
        if moveDown and player.bottom < WINDOW_HEIGHT:
            player.top += MOVE_SPEED
        if moveUp and player.top > 0:
            player.top -= MOVE_SPEED
        if moveLeft and player.left > 0:
            player.left -= MOVE_SPEED
        if moveRight and player.right < WINDOW_WIDTH:
            player.right += MOVE_SPEED



    def draw(self, surface):

        windowSurface.blit(playerImage, player)
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
\boars.py

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pygame, sys, random, math

class Boar(object):

    boarCounter = 0
    NEW_BOAR = 40
    BOAR_SIZE = 64

    boars = []
        for i in range (10):
            boars.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH
            - BOAR_SIZE), random.randint (0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - BOAR_SIZE),
            BOAR_SIZE, BOAR_SIZE))

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def update(self):

        stepMovementNegativeBoar = random.randrange(0, -6, -2)

        stepMovementPositiveBoar = random.randrange(0, 6, 2)

        boarMovement = [((stepMovementNegativeBoar),0), ((stepMovementPositiveBoar), 0)
                          , (0, (stepMovementNegativeBoar)), (0, (stepMovementPositiveBoar))]
        for boar in boars:
            boar.move_ip(*random.choice(boarMovement))

        for boar in boars[:]:

            if player.colliderect(boar):
                windowSurface.blit(boarImageTwo, boar)
                windowSurface.blit(playerImageTwo, player)

            def explosionBoar():
                for boar in boars:
                    if player.colliderect(boar) and (moveLeft == False and
            moveRight == False and moveUp == False and
            moveDown == False):
                         boars.remove(boar)

            if player.colliderect(boar) and (moveLeft == False and
            moveRight == False and moveUp == False and moveDown == False):
                #timer inställningar
                tBoar = Timer(10, explosionPig)
                tBoar.start()

    def draw(self, surface):

        boarCounter += 1
        if boarCounter >= NEW_BOAR:
            boarCounter = 0
            boars.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH
        - BOAR_SIZE), random.randint (0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - BOAR_SIZE),
        BOAR_SIZE, BOAR_SIZE))
```

Comment: There's far too much code here.

Comment: I'm afraid it is better to start over and copy usable parts from the code above. Before you do, read up on OOP, object oriented programming, which is the official name for what you refer to as OOC I guess. You will have more hits.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start of with files.

You can divide your code into smaller files that contain code specific to a function. For example, you can have a file main that will show the menu, and after picking the difficulty, it will create a Game object and start the game.

You can have classes like Rabbit, Boar etc, that will have methods `draw` and `update` where you can keep their behavior in their update method. You can keep the classes in separate files too.

All images, and sounds can be put into dictionaries. This way you will avoid having 20 variables, instead you will have 1 variable, for example sound_dict that will contain keys like fox, rabbit etc.

You can also have a Player class that will have the same methods as the other classes, but also a method that will respond to player input. I would do something along these lines:

```
def process_event(event):
    if event.type == MOUSEDOWN:
       if event.key == K_LEFT:
           self.x -= MOVESPEED
```

This way you can have 1 event loop in the game, and call all the necessary objects that need to process it. It moves the action response to the individual objects.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    player.process_event(event)
```

If your levels are similar, but have different enemies, you could have just game loop, and depending on the level, just prepare it accordingly to the level to be played.

If there is not a distinction between enemies, you can keep them in one list. They can respond differently, since they have different things in their update methods.

Functions make the code much easier to read, don't be afraid of using too much of them.

EDIT:

The code looks a bit better, but you have some unnecessary things in you player event handling.  The player should not handle the QUIT event, this should be done in the main event loop.

Instead of having a class of `Boars` have a class of `Boar` that will have the information of 1 boar. A boar will have a position. As of now, you add new boards in your draw function. You should create the Boars list once, and call a draw method on each Boar.

You have an empty Player `__init__` method. Since the player has states - moveRight, moveLeft, you can initialize them by writing `self.moveRight = False`.
Then the event handling would assign True to self.moveRight of the player.

Comment: Take a look at the progress, please. @Bartlomiej Lewandowski

Comment: Do you mean by dictionary this? `soundsDict = {"foxSound" : "pygame.mixer.sound(sound/foxSound.wav)"}`

Comment: close, right now you have a dictionary with the key and value being both strings, you want to have the value type to be the sound, so this will work: `soundsDict = {"fox" : pygame.mixer.sound("sound/foxSound.wav")}`

Comment: So does the main file look correct so far, I'm not sure where in the code the functions should be.

Comment: Updated all the coding to recent version. Don't know if correct or not.